# How is "Cut" command in Windows executed globally and why data recovery is not possible?

Tags: windows, explorer

So, I wondered several times, what's the actual low-level difference when using "Cut" command in Windows, apart from Copy-Paste-Delete one, with focus being on the "Delete" part.

However, until now it wasn't really important, but I had some issues recently when using Cut-Paste in my application, when having an error in the process. The file that was being Cut-Pasted doesn't exist anymore, and can't be recovered by any data recovery software out there.

So I ran some tests, and it seems that it's true.

Anybody knows how the Cut-Paste commant works?

Comment: Deleted files aren't always retrievable.  The fact that you couldn't retrieve the file on this particular occasion is almost certainly a coincidence, and has nothing to do with the fact that it was deleted via Cut.  (Except insofar as that if you'd deleted it with Explorer's Delete function, it would have been put in the recycle bin rather than actually being deleted.)

Answer (score 6):

### The clipboard

Windows manages an internal object called `The Clipboard` and provides an interface to put data in the clipboard, get the data from the clipboard, get meta information about the content of the clipboard (check if it is empty or there is any data there, get the type of the data a.s.o.). The operations with the clipboard (get, put) have **copy** semantics. They do not destroy the source data. The object currently kept in the clipboard can be get from there any time you want, it is not removed after the first "get" operation.

The clipboard can store a single object at any time. When an application puts something in the clipboard the previous content of the clipboard is lost. The clipboard can store the same data in multiple formats; is the application's responsibility to put it there in multiple formats, to query about the available formats and get the data in the format it wants. For example, an HTML-editor can put in the clipboard both the HTML source code of the selected text and the text as it is rendered in the browser (with different colors and fonts etc). Then, the same application or another application either gets the needed format depending on the context or provides a "Paste Special" command where it asks the user what format to use (see Microsoft Office programs or OpenOffice programs for example).

The clipboard is available (through the operations provided by Windows) to all the applications that want to use it and it is a powerful method to transfer data between applications. However, due to different formats used by different applications, it is not always possible to get data from an application and put it into another one. For example, a plain text editor like Notepad cannot `Paste` an image previously put in the clipboard by Paint, Photoshop or another graphic editor. This happens because Notepad just don't know how to handle anything but plain text.

### The `Cut`, `Copy` and `Paste` semantic for applications that handle content (text, images etc)

It's up to each application how they use the clipboard. Implementing the Cut, Copy and Paste operations **usually** means:

- `Cut` - the application puts (copies) to the clipboard the object selected in the document then remove it from the document;
- `Copy` - the application puts (copies) to the clipboard the object selected in the document (but it does not remove it from the document);
- `Paste` - the application gets (copies) from the clipboard the object stored there and puts into the current document; depending on the application, it is either inserted at the position of the caret, or replaces the current selection or it is simply inserted into the current container (folder or directory, in Windows Explorer); the content of the clipboard is not changed; a subsequent `Paste` is possible and it will do the same;

### The `Cut`, `Copy` and `Paste` semantic for applications that handle files (Windows Explorer, for example)

Windows Explorer and other programs that works with files and not with pieces of text or image use a different semantic. The biggest difference from the model above is that Windows Explorer works with file names (with full paths) and not with the content of those files. It does not reads the file and it **does not** place the content of the file in the clipboard.

- `Cut` - Windows Explorer copies the full **path** of the file into the clipboard; it also sets an internal flag that says *"the file whose path is in the clipboard is meant to be moved by the next `Paste`"*; it uses this flag to be able to render the *cut* file dimmed in all its windows until the operation completes or is aborted; it does not move or remove the file at this point;
- `Copy` - Windows Explorer copies the full **path** of the file into the clipboard; it does not touch the file itself; then it clears the flag that was set on the last `Cut` operation; the file that was previously **cut** (if any) is now rendered again using the same style as the other files (no dim, no nothing); in other words, a `Copy` cancels any previous `Cut`;
- `Paste` - Windows Explorer gets the file path from the clipboard; it **copies** the file pointed by that path into the current directory; what it does after that depends on its internal flag for `Cut` operation; if the flag is set then the file was **cut** before (see `Cut` and `Copy` above) then it will remove the file from their original location and also the flag; otherwise (when the `Cut` flag is not set because the last operation was a `Copy`), it does not affect the original file in any way.

#### Remarks on Windows Explorer's behaviour

It's important to notice that Windows Explorer **does not** put the file content in the clipboard. If you use the `Cut` or `Copy` command in Explorer then you delete the file, it will not be able to `Paste` it in a different directory because the file does not exist any more and it cannot copy an object that does not exist.

Also, a file that was `Cut` in Windows Explorer cannot be `Paste`d multiple times in different directories because Explorer pairs the `Cut` with the first `Paste` (if there was no `Copy` in the meantime) and produces a move operations from them. After the `Paste` the `Cut` flag is removed and, even if it is not removed, there is no way to move the file again because it is not on the path stored in clipboard any more.

I'm not on Windows now (I didn't use Windows in the last 3 years) but as far as I remember, you can `Copy` a file once then `Paste` it several times; a `Copy` followed by a `Paste` produces a copy of the file and as long as the source is still there, subsequent `Paste` operations can produce more copies.

Sure, an error that happens on the most inconvenient moment can produce data loss. Due to the way Windows Explorer handles the files and the errors that might happen, it is very unlikely that it accidentally removes a file during a `Cut`-`Paste` operation without putting it into the destination folder.

I'm absolutely confident that more files are lost due to human error than because of errors that happen during the execution of Windows Explorer.

### Other applications

Other applications work in different ways. **Most** of those that deal with content (text, image, sound, video, etc) work as explained in the section about content. **Most** of those that deal with files work similar with Windows Explorer.

Another application can get the data that was put in the clipboard but Windows Explorer. It's up to that application to interpret it as plain text and put the file path it gets from clipboard into the current document as is (Notepad works this way) or recognize it is a file path and attempt to copy the file (or do something else with it). Another window or instance of Explorer does it, maybe other file managers do it too.

### Multiple-clipboard applications

The programs from the Microsoft Office Suite (Word, Excel a.s.o) and also some other applications implement a multiple-clipboard feature. This functionality is not provided by Windows clipboard. These applications work with the clipboard as usual but the also keep a history of the objects they put into the clipboard in the past and offer the user a list of these objects for re-use. For compatibility and integration with other applications they also get from and put into the clipboard the object that the user selects for re-use. The Windows clipboard, however, still contains a single object, the last one that was put there by any application.

Comment: Thanks for a very extended answer, but it, however, doesn't really answer my question(s)...  It clarifies a lot, but not all.
Firstly: yes, its true that much more data is lost due to human error rather than explorer's execution, but it does happen (can't bet my life on the "always" adition here, but...) that the file is lost if "Cut" operation is interrupted in an unusual way (meaning: NOT by Canceling the operation, but, for example, removing the source or destination drive....)

Comment: Secondly: It's still very unclear as to why the file that was removed from the source folder/drive by the completion/interruption of the command "Cut" can't be retrieved the same was as if the file is deleted by usual way (aka removed from recycler or shift+del recycler bypassed....).

How is the file deletion on the "Cut" flag executed is my main question here.  First guess would be it's overwritten by zeroes, but then again, I can't find a logical explanation as to why would it do it that way if so...

Comment: A normal file removal does not overwrite its content neither with zeroes, nor with something else. It is only removed from the file systems bookkeeping and the disk blocks its data uses are marked as free and they can be freely used whenever they are needed by the file system to store the data of another file. There is no reason for the file system to overwrite any data it deletes; it is a costly process (takes time, stresses the hardware) and I don't think any file system designed for the final customer use does this. I cannot tell about CIA computers (and such), however :-)

Comment: But... Windows is a multi-tasking OS. All the time it's up and running there are a lot of programs that also run. Some are launched by the user, others are background processes. Many of them work with files, some create temporary files under the hood, write data in them then delete them. It's highly possible that after your file was deleted, the space it used to occupy was immediately used to store another file that was just created by one of the other programs. This way the information that could be used to recover your file was overwritten and your file disappeared without leaving a trace.

Comment: It happened to me several times while attempting to recover a file removed several minutes ago to get a lot of files of those existence and content I was not aware before and to be impossible to find the file I wanted. For performance reasons the file system keeps in memory a cache of the recently used data blocks; when a new file is created, a lot of times it replaces the last deleted file (because the data block released by that file is in the cache). It's sad but understandable: the file systems are designed to react fast on the most used file operations and file recovery is not one of them